# How to get the point of Visual HitTest when using a geometry as a hit test parameter

Tags: wpf, intersection, point, hittest

When you use a geometry for the hit test parameter is there a way to get the point of intersection (i.e. hit) between the two geometries, right now it only says that it has been hit and the HitTestResult from what I can see doesn't provide any such info.

Comment: If you use an `EllipseGeometry` and you get a `Button` for example in the HitTest Callback then the intersection is an area and not a point. It's like the overlap of a rectangle and a circle. I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: @Meleak, in my case the intersection is only a point(s), for example a line and some shape like ellipse. Even if I wanted the geometry how can i get the geometry from HitTestResult, because maybe then I can use the bounds property to get the coordinates of where the new geometry is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it can be done. If you are looking for finding the intersection between two geometries look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353383/combinegeometry-between-an-ellipse-and-a-line-getting-no-intersection/7353771#7353771).

Comment: WPF contains a hittesting framework that is incredibly helpful for determining what to test with what, but when you dive into *drawing* on your own, you often need to write your HitTestCore - because only you (as the 'artist') are able to tell what is what.On the other hand,if you use existing toplevel classes-hit testing just works. Maybe your problem is just in that you delved too deep? Maybe you just used a wrong tool to solve previous problem? Have you tried assembling your graphics into a UserControl with canvas and many System.Windows.Shape.Path/Line/Elipse instead of drawing geometries?