# CombineGeometry between an Ellipse and a Line getting no intersection

Tags: wpf, geometry, line, ellipse

So I tested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341133/what-is-wrong-with-the-following-code) code (intersection between two ellipses, look at the accepted answer), but if I change one of the ellipses to a line geometry (or path geometry representing a line) and it gives me no intersection. Does any one know why? Does combine geometry work on area of the geometry, and since lines have no area, it gives no intersection?

Since eventually I would want to see if the arbitrary path geometries intersect. I guess I would have to find a way to "pad" the path with some area, if there is no solution to just using a path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason I guess line geometry is not considered as a geometry, maybe just some sort of a stroke? Anyway, you need to do `GetWidenedPathGeometry` on your path and it would give you a geometry defined by the shape of the stroke.

Comment: If you think about that in terms if visuals and screen areas, this becames obvious: a line has ZERO width. Nothing intersects with it, as its effective area is ZERO. A stroked line has some area, thus something can intersect with it with nonempty result.